# Does windbg aliases really be expanded when a new block of code is entered?

Tags: windbg

"An alias consists of an alias name and an alias equivalent. When you use an alias name as part of a debugger command, the name is automatically replaced by the alias equivalent. This replacement occurs immediately, before the command is parsed or executed." All above is from windbg help document. The following is the content of my windbg script file.

```
ad /q *
;aS MyVar 0x7b;
.block
{
    ;aS /x ${/v:MyVar}  ${MyVar}+0x1;
    .block
    {
        .printf "MyVar1=0x%x\n",${MyVar};
        .block
        {
            .printf "MyVar2=0x%x\n",${MyVar};
        }
        .printf "MyVar3=0x%x\n",${MyVar};
    }

    .block
    {
        .printf "MyVar4=0x%x\n",${MyVar};
    }

}
.block
{
    .printf "MyVar5=0x%x\n",${MyVar};
}

al;
```

The following is the result of executing this script.

```
0:000> $$><c:\windbg.wds
MyVar1=0x7b
MyVar2=0x7b
MyVar3=0x7b
MyVar4=0x7b
MyVar5=0x7c
  Alias            Value  
 -------          ------- 
 MyVar            0x7c
```

I don't know why the first four line result occured,so I come here to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From WinDbg `aS` help:

> Note that if the portion of the line after the semicolon requires expansion of the alias, you must enclose that second portion of the line in a new block.

From WinDbg `.block` help:

> When each block is entered, all aliases within the block are evaluated. If you alter the value of an alias at some point within a command block, commands subsequent to that point will not use the new alias value unless they are within a subordinate block.

where *subordinate* obviously has the meaning of *following* and not *nested*.

So yes, you have found another limitation of WinDbg's scripting language. I recommend looking at alternatives such as [PyKd](https://pykd.codeplex.com/) or similar.